# Using regex in php to find string values between characters multiple times

Tags: php, regex

Here I have a string, `"Hello World! I am trying out regex in PHP!"`. What I want to do is retrieve string values between a set of characters. In this example, the characters are `** **`

```
$str = "**Hello World!** I am trying out regex in PHP!";
preg_match('#\*\*(.*)\*\*#Us', $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

This will echo out "Hello World!", but I want to echo out several matches:

```
$str = "**Hello World!** I am trying out **regex in PHP!**";
```

How would I be able to do so? I tried using `preg_match_all()` but I don't think I was using it properly, or that it would work at all in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = "**Hello World!** I am trying out **regex in PHP!**";
preg_match_all('/\*{2}([^*]*)\*{2}/', $str, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
Array
(
    [0] => Hello World!
    [1] => regex in PHP!
)
```

Even your regex `#\*\*(.*)\*\*#Us` should work with this but my suggested regex is little more efficient due to negation based pattern `[^*]*`

Answer (score 2):

You got 1 match owing to using preg_match.You should use preg_match_all Here is another pattern.It uses word non word match between the delimiters

```
<?php
    $str = "**Hello World!** I am trying out **regex in PHP!**";
    $regex='/\*\*([\w\W]*)\*\*/iU';
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $m); 
    print_r($m[1]);
```

Comment: Which part of your regex is benefiting from that `i` pattern modifier?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a non-greedy form of regex. Because i think you want to match also the contents (*text inside ***)  where the single `*`  resides.

```
$str = "**Hello World!** I am trying out **regex in PHP!**";
preg_match_all('~\*\*(.*?)\*\*~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oY0vG1/1)